# Searching for Tweets in last one hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am building a social analytics app. I need to find the number of tweets containing a certain word in the past one hour (time range may vary).

How do I do this?

I tried these:
1. using `until` param - But it doesnt support time and heard its unreliable
2. Fetching max possible tweets and filtering by date and time - computationally intensive

how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an sql database and that the title of the tweet should contain a certain word, this should do the trick.

```
Tweet.where('created_at >= ? AND title LIKE ?', 1.hour.ago, '%some_word%')
```

Comment: dude Im fetching from twitter!